# How to change selected cell index Color on Hstack

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I write the following code to Show the data in HStack on scroll view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            VStack {
             
                //MARK: CALENDAR
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
                    HStack(spacing: 20){
                        Calendar(number: "9", days: "tue", color: #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1), textcolor: #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1))
                        Calendar(number: "10", days: "Wed", color: #colorLiteral(red: 0.9060331583, green: 0.2547450066, blue: 0.3359550834, alpha: 1), textcolor: #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1))
                        Calendar(number: "11", days: "Thu", color: #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1), textcolor: #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1))
                        Calendar(number: "12", days: "Fri", color: #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1), textcolor: #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1))
                        Calendar(number: "13", days: "Sat", color: #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1), textcolor: #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1))
                        Calendar(number: "14", days: "Sun", color: #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1), textcolor: #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1))
                        
                    }
                    .padding(.leading,10)
                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
                    .shadow(radius: 3, x: 3, y: 3)
                }
               
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

 struct Calendar: View {
    var number : String
    var days : String
    var color : UIColor
    var textcolor : UIColor
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(self.number)
                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                .foregroundColor(Color(self.textcolor))
            Text(self.days)
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(Color(self.textcolor))
        }.padding([.top,.bottom], 10)
            .padding([.leading,.trailing],10)
            .background(Color(self.color))
            .cornerRadius(30)
    }
}
```

It shows:

[image: Output]

How do I change the selected index Background color?

And I want to show the current one-week dates and week name here is any advice or help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want something like this?

[image: Current day is highlighted]

If you want to...

- Display the days of the current week
- Make the current day red

... then you can't hardcode your dates.

```
             NO! ↓          ↓             ↓
Calendar(number: "9", days: "tue", color: #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1), textcolor: #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1))
```

First, you'll need to get the current days of the week (using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62355272/14351818)). Then, you can use `DateFormatter` to make it human-readable, like "25" or "Tue". Also, you'll need to rename your `Calendar` into something unique like `CalendarView`, because `Calendar` is the name of a built-in struct.

```
struct CalendarDay: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var number: String
    var weekday: String
    var isToday: Bool
}
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var days = [CalendarDay]()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            VStack {
                
                //MARK: CALENDAR
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
                    HStack(spacing: 20) {
                        
                        ForEach(days) { day in
                            CalendarView(
                                number: day.number,
                                days: day.weekday,
                                color: day.isToday ? #colorLiteral(red: 0.9060331583, green: 0.2547450066, blue: 0.3359550834, alpha: 1) : #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1),
                                textcolor: day.isToday ? #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1) : #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
                            )
                        }
                    }
                    .padding(.leading,10)
                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
                    .shadow(radius: 3, x: 3, y: 3)
                }
                
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            getCurrentWeekdays()
        }
    }
    
    func getCurrentWeekdays() {
        /// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/62355272/14351818
        let dateComponents = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: Date())
        let startOfWeek = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).date(from: dateComponents)!
        let startOfWeekNoon = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: startOfWeek)!
        
        days = (0...6).map {
            let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
            let date = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: $0, to: startOfWeekNoon)!
            
            let numberDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            numberDateFormatter.dateFormat = "d"
            let number = numberDateFormatter.string(from: date)
            
            let weekdayDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            weekdayDateFormatter.dateFormat = "E"
            let weekday = weekdayDateFormatter.string(from: date)
            
            let calendarDay = CalendarDay(
                number: number,
                weekday: weekday,
                isToday: calendar.component(.day, from: Date()) == calendar.component(.day, from: date)
            )
            
            return calendarDay
        }
        
    }
}

struct CalendarView: View {
    var number : String
    var days : String
    var color : UIColor
    var textcolor : UIColor
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(self.number)
                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                .foregroundColor(Color(self.textcolor))
            Text(self.days)
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(Color(self.textcolor))
        }.padding([.top,.bottom], 10)
        .padding([.leading,.trailing],10)
        .background(Color(self.color))
        .cornerRadius(30)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @aheze exactly, ineed change the selected date color also