# Change selected cell Baground Color in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, selection, hstack

I write the following code and brought this kind of output.[image: output]

By using the .onTapGesture method I find the selected day from HStack

But I want to change the background color based on cell selection in Hstack.

Anyone give some idea or suggestions for changing the selected cell Background color on HStack.

Or share any references with me.

```
struct CalendarDay: Identifiable {
                let id = UUID()
                var number: String
                var weekday: String
                var isToday: Bool
            }
            struct ContentView: View {
                @State var days = [CalendarDay]()
                
                var body: some View {
                    ZStack{
                        VStack {
                            
                            //MARK: CALENDAR
                            ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
                                HStack(spacing: 20) {
                                    
                                    ForEach(days) { day in
                                        CalendarView(
                                            number: day.number,
                                            days: day.weekday,
                                            color: day.isToday ? #colorLiteral(red: 0.9060331583, green: 0.2547450066, blue: 0.3359550834, alpha: 1) : #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1),
                                            textcolor: day.isToday ? #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1) : #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
                                        )
    .onTapGesture{
    print(day)
    }
                                    }
                                }
                                .padding(.leading,10)
                                .padding(.bottom, 10)
                                .shadow(radius: 3, x: 3, y: 3)
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                    .onAppear {
                        getCurrentWeekdays()
                    }
                }
                
                func getCurrentWeekdays() {
                    /// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/62355272/14351818
                    let dateComponents = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: Date())
                    let startOfWeek = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).date(from: dateComponents)!
                    let startOfWeekNoon = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: startOfWeek)!
                    
                    days = (0...6).map {
                        let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
                        let date = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: $0, to: startOfWeekNoon)!
                        
                        let numberDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                        numberDateFormatter.dateFormat = "d"
                        let number = numberDateFormatter.string(from: date)
                        
                        let weekdayDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                        weekdayDateFormatter.dateFormat = "E"
                        let weekday = weekdayDateFormatter.string(from: date)
                        
                        let calendarDay = CalendarDay(
                            number: number,
                            weekday: weekday,
                            isToday: calendar.component(.day, from: Date()) == calendar.component(.day, from: date)
                        )
                        
                        return calendarDay
                    }
                    
                }
            }
            
            struct CalendarView: View {
                var number : String
                var days : String
                var color : UIColor
                var textcolor : UIColor
                
                var body: some View {
                    VStack{
                        Text(self.number)
                            .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                            .foregroundColor(Color(self.textcolor))
                        Text(self.days)
                            .font(.headline)
                            .foregroundColor(Color(self.textcolor))
                    }.padding([.top,.bottom], 10)
                    .padding([.leading,.trailing],10)
                    .background(Color(self.color))
                    .cornerRadius(30)
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct CalendarDay: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var number: String
    var weekday: String
    var isToday: Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var days = [CalendarDay]()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            VStack {
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
                    HStack(spacing: 20) {
                        
                    //  <--- 
                    ForEach(days.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                        CalendarView(
                            number: days[i].number,
                            days: days[i].weekday,
                            color: days[i].isToday ? #colorLiteral(red: 0.9060331583, green: 0.2547450066, blue: 0.3359550834, alpha: 1) : #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1),
                            textcolor: days[i].isToday ? #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1) : #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
                        )
                            .onTapGesture{
                                print(days[i])
                                // this is just for replacing the current selection
                                for j in days.indices { days[j].isToday = false }
                                days[i].isToday = true
                            }
                    }
                  //  <---

                    }
                    .padding(.leading,10)
                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
                    .shadow(radius: 3, x: 3, y: 3)
                }
                
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            getCurrentWeekdays()
        }
    }
    
    func getCurrentWeekdays() {
        /// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/62355272/14351818
        let dateComponents = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: Date())
        let startOfWeek = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).date(from: dateComponents)!
        let startOfWeekNoon = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: startOfWeek)!
        
        days = (0...6).map {
            let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
            let date = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: $0, to: startOfWeekNoon)!
            
            let numberDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            numberDateFormatter.dateFormat = "d"
            let number = numberDateFormatter.string(from: date)
            
            let weekdayDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            weekdayDateFormatter.dateFormat = "E"
            let weekday = weekdayDateFormatter.string(from: date)
            
            let calendarDay = CalendarDay(
                number: number,
                weekday: weekday,
                isToday: calendar.component(.day, from: Date()) == calendar.component(.day, from: date)
            )
            
            return calendarDay
        }
        
    }
}

struct CalendarView: View {
    var number : String
    var days : String
    var color : UIColor
    var textcolor : UIColor
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(self.number)
                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                .foregroundColor(Color(self.textcolor))
            Text(self.days)
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(Color(self.textcolor))
        }.padding([.top,.bottom], 10)
            .padding([.leading,.trailing],10)
            .background(Color(self.color))
            .cornerRadius(30)
    }
}
```

Comment: Gives error: Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols; calling functions with SwiftUI

Comment: updated the answer to give full code I'm using.

Comment: It gives the same error in For line: ForEach(days.indices, id: \.self) { i in

Comment: ok, try this new code, maybe it is to do with me using the latest xcode and macos.

Comment: if this answer your question, please mark it as correct.