# Add forward and Backward buttons on Hstack in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, hstack

I write the following code for date picker customization, and get the output as [image: Output image]

Here I want to add the forward and Backword buttons for the Date picker this way [image: Expect output]

Anyone help me with my code modification to add forward and Backword buttons with [Expect output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA9v3.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zA9v3.png)

Give any idea or share any references with me.

```
    struct CalendarDay: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var number: String
    var weekday: String
    var isToday: Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var days = [CalendarDay]()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            VStack {
                
                Button(action:{
                    //Button Action
                    })
                    .padding(.leading, 10)
                Spacer()
                ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
                    HStack(spacing: 20) {
                  ForEach(days.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                        CalendarView(
                            number: self.days[i].number,
                            days: self.days[i].weekday,
                            color: self.days[i].isToday ? #colorLiteral(red: 0.9060331583, green: 0.2547450066, blue: 0.3359550834, alpha: 1) : #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1),
                            textcolor: self.days[i].isToday ? #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1) : #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
                        )
                            .onTapGesture{
                                print(self.days[i])
                                // this is just for replacing the current selection
                                for j in self.days.indices { self.days[j].isToday = false }
                                self.days[i].isToday = true
                            }
                    }}
                    .padding(.leading,10)
                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
                    .shadow(radius: 3, x: 3, y: 3)
                }
                Spacer()
                Button(action:{
                                   //Button Action
                                   })
                                   .padding(.leading)
                               Spacer()
                
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.getCurrentWeekdays()
        }
    }
    
    func getCurrentWeekdays() {
        /// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/62355272/14351818
        let dateComponents = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: Date())
        let startOfWeek = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).date(from: dateComponents)!
        let startOfWeekNoon = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: startOfWeek)!
        
        days = (0...6).map {
            let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
            let date = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: $0, to: startOfWeekNoon)!
            
            let numberDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            numberDateFormatter.dateFormat = "d"
            let number = numberDateFormatter.string(from: date)
            
            let weekdayDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            weekdayDateFormatter.dateFormat = "E"
            let weekday = weekdayDateFormatter.string(from: date)
            
            let calendarDay = CalendarDay(
                number: number,
                weekday: weekday,
                isToday: calendar.component(.day, from: Date()) == calendar.component(.day, from: date)
            )
            
            return calendarDay
        }
        
    }
}

struct CalendarView: View {
    var number : String
    var days : String
    var color : UIColor
    var textcolor : UIColor
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(self.number)
                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                .foregroundColor(Color(self.textcolor))
            Text(self.days)
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(Color(self.textcolor))
        }.padding([.top,.bottom], 10)
            .padding([.leading,.trailing],10)
            .background(Color(self.color))
            .cornerRadius(30)
    }
}
```

Comment: what have you tried to add the buttons of your question?

Comment: Add the my tried code

Answer (score 1):

you could try something like this: edited for ScrollViewReader

```
struct ContentView: View {

@State var days = [CalendarDay]()
@State var selectedDay: Int = 0

var body: some View {
    ScrollViewReader { scrollProxy in
        HStack {
            Button(action: {
                if selectedDay > 0 {
                    for j in days.indices { days[j].isToday = false }
                    days[selectedDay-1].isToday = true
                    selectedDay -= 1
                    withAnimation { scrollProxy.scrollTo(selectedDay) }
                }
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.left.circle.fill")
            }
            ZStack{
                VStack {
                    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
                        HStack(spacing: 20) {
                            ForEach(days.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                                CalendarView(
                                    number: days[i].number,
                                    days: days[i].weekday,
                                    color: days[i].isToday ? #colorLiteral(red: 0.9060331583, green: 0.2547450066, blue: 0.3359550834, alpha: 1) : #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1),
                                    textcolor: days[i].isToday ? #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1) : #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
                                ).onTapGesture {
                                    selectedDay = i
                                    for j in days.indices {
                                        if j == i {
                                            days[i].isToday = true
                                        } else {
                                            days[j].isToday = false
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            
                        }
                        .padding(.leading,10)
                        .padding(.bottom, 10)
                        .shadow(radius: 3, x: 3, y: 3)
                    }
                }
            }
            Button(action: {
                if selectedDay < days.count-1 {
                    for j in days.indices { days[j].isToday = false }
                    days[selectedDay+1].isToday = true
                    selectedDay += 1
                    withAnimation { scrollProxy.scrollTo(selectedDay) }
                }
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "chevron.right.circle.fill")
            }
        }
    }
    .onAppear {
        getCurrentWeekdays()
    }
}
    
    func getCurrentWeekdays() {
        /// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/62355272/14351818
        let dateComponents = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: Date())
        let startOfWeek = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).date(from: dateComponents)!
        let startOfWeekNoon = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: startOfWeek)!
        
        days = (0...6).map {
            let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
            let date = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: $0, to: startOfWeekNoon)!
            
            let numberDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            numberDateFormatter.dateFormat = "d"
            let number = numberDateFormatter.string(from: date)
            
            let weekdayDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            weekdayDateFormatter.dateFormat = "E"
            let weekday = weekdayDateFormatter.string(from: date)
            
            let calendarDay = CalendarDay(
                number: number,
                weekday: weekday,
                isToday: calendar.component(.day, from: Date()) == calendar.component(.day, from: date)
            )
            //  <--- here --->
            if calendar.component(.day, from: Date()) == calendar.component(.day, from: date) {
                selectedDay = $0
            }
            
            return calendarDay
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: When the displayed days completed with forwarding action automatically scroll is not working.

Comment: You can implement `ScrollViewReader` to automatically scroll to the selected date.

Comment: if this answered your question, please click the "check mark" button under the vote buttons.

Comment: if I selected in the middle and choose backword and forward it's not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try like below-:

You can replace `Text` view with `Image` view for buttons. The Back and forward buttons retain their positions, while the date selector is still scrollable.

```
import SwiftUI

struct CalendarDay: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var number: String
    var weekday: String
    var isToday: Bool
}

struct Test1: View {
    @State var days = [CalendarDay]()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack(){
            Button {
                
            } label: {
                
                ZStack {
                    
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.red)
                        .opacity(0.6)
                    
                    Circle()
                        .strokeBorder(Color.red, lineWidth: 1)
                    
                    Text("B").foregroundColor(.white)
                    
                }.frame(width: 30, height: 30)
            }.padding([.leading],3)
            
            HStack(alignment:.center){
                GeometryReader{ proxy in
                    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                        
                        LazyHStack {
                            ForEach(days.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                                CalendarView(
                                    number: days[i].number,
                                    days: days[i].weekday,
                                    color: days[i].isToday ? #colorLiteral(red: 0.9060331583, green: 0.2547450066, blue: 0.3359550834, alpha: 1) : #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1),
                                    textcolor: days[i].isToday ? #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1) : #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1), proxy: proxy
                                )
                                .onTapGesture{
                                    print(days[i])
                                    // this is just for replacing the current selection
                                    for j in days.indices { days[j].isToday = false }
                                    days[i].isToday = true
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding([.trailing,.leading],3)
            
            
            Button {
                
            } label: {
                ZStack {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.red)
                        .opacity(0.6)
                    
                    Circle()
                        .strokeBorder(Color.red, lineWidth: 1)
                    
                    Text("F").foregroundColor(.white)
                }.frame(width: 30, height: 30)
            }.padding([.trailing],3)
        }
        
        .shadow(radius: 3, x: 3, y: 3)
        .onAppear {
            getCurrentWeekdays()
        }
    }
    
    func getCurrentWeekdays() {
        /// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/62355272/14351818
        let dateComponents = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).dateComponents([.yearForWeekOfYear, .weekOfYear], from: Date())
        let startOfWeek = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).date(from: dateComponents)!
        let startOfWeekNoon = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).date(bySettingHour: 12, minute: 0, second: 0, of: startOfWeek)!
        
        days = (0...20).map {
            let calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
            let date = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: $0, to: startOfWeekNoon)!
            
            let numberDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            numberDateFormatter.dateFormat = "d"
            let number = numberDateFormatter.string(from: date)
            
            let weekdayDateFormatter = DateFormatter()
            weekdayDateFormatter.dateFormat = "E"
            let weekday = weekdayDateFormatter.string(from: date)
            
            let calendarDay = CalendarDay(
                number: number,
                weekday: weekday,
                isToday: calendar.component(.day, from: Date()) == calendar.component(.day, from: date)
            )
            
            return calendarDay
        }
        
    }
}
struct CalendarView: View {
    var number : String
    var days : String
    var color : UIColor
    var textcolor : UIColor
    var proxy: GeometryProxy
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(self.number)
                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold, design: .rounded))
                .foregroundColor(Color(self.textcolor))
            Text(self.days)
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(Color(self.textcolor))
        }
        
        .frame(width: proxy.size.width * 0.18, height:  proxy.size.width * 0.2)
        .background(Color(self.color))
        .cornerRadius(30)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Need last 5 days from current day